# Mongoose array of sub document are not saving in parent document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
const KeyContactsPersonsSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    required: true,
    type: String
  },
  contactNumber: {
    required: true,
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    required: true,
    type: String
  }
});
```

the above define schema has been included in below schemas keyContactsPersons attribute

```
const CompanySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true
  },
  address: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  contactNumber: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  logo: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  keyContactsPersons: [KeyContactsPersonsSchema],
  billingDetails: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  assignedEmployee: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  status: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});
```

finally save the model
JSON object passed to CompanyModel is like.while Im trying to save this it gives me a error like

> keyContactsPersons.0.email: Path `email` is required.,
>   keyContactsPersons.0.contactNumber: Path `contactNumber` is required.,
>   keyContactsPersons.0.name: Path `name` is required.

```
"company":{
        "name":"Leafy Code",
        "address":"Hokandara",
        "contactNumber":"075227785",
        "logo":"/logo",
        "billingDetails":"billingDetails",
        "assignedEmployee":"5997e71ab6a13500018106b9",
        "status": true,
        "keyContactsPersons": [
            {
                "name":"demo person",
                "contactNumber":"0771568952",
                "email":"testmail@gmail.com"
            }   
        ]
    }


const newCompany = new CompanyModel(company);
newCompany.save();
```

Comment: Is `company` variable you give to `CompanyModel` equals to `"company": ...` like: `company = { "company" : ... }` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from the code included in your question that the **company** variable passed here, *CompanyModel(company)* contains the object **{ "company": { ... } }**.

You schema does not have a **company** property, so the object should be like this:

```
const company = {
  "name": "Leafy Code",
  "address": "Hokandara",
  "contactNumber": "075227785",
  "logo": "/logo",
  "billingDetails": "billingDetails",
  "assignedEmployee": "5997e71ab6a13500018106b9",
  "status": true,
  "keyContactsPersons": [{
    "name": "demo person",
    "contactNumber": "0771568952",
    "email": "testmail@gmail.com"
  }]
}

const newCompany = new CompanyModel(company)
newCompany.save()
```